# Unable to find a matching line for sublist apply with key:

Tags: netsuite

We are seeing failure to Netsuite while updating payments via the netsuite API,

the error message we see is as below `Unable to find a matching line for sublist apply with key: [doc,line] and value: [123344,null]` where `123344` is the `external id` of the bill.
Any ideas what might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 6):

Note that SuiteTalk will give you this cryptic little message when you try to create a payment for an invoice that already has an `Invoice:Paid In Full` transaction status.

Don't get me wrong—it's good that NetSuite has this sanity check. I just wish the error was more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

"Unable to find a matching line for sublist apply with key: [doc,line] and value: [123344,**null**]"

There is your problem, you can't match a line if you are not passing the line number.

Comment: What is the doc number used for

Comment: @NaveenRaj The doc is the internal id of the object you're applying to, in this case it should be an invoice or bill.

Comment: @drewish Thank you .. I got to know it little earlier but your post should help others people. Voted up for the comment

Comment: What is the line used for?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem inserting new payments, but it worked using the Internal ID for the Invoice column.

Note that the mapping specification is not clear on how to identify the Invoice when adding/updating payments for it. The API requires an invoice, and it works when you provide the Internal ID for the invoice.

Comment: My recollection is that if the document you're referencing has only one line item you don't need to specify it (might default to 0?), but if there are multiple line items you'll need to provide a line number.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when creating a customer payment. Below is my code. Make sure `invoiceId` is invoice's internal id and `amount` is less than or equal to invoice amount.

```
CustomerPaymentApply paymentApply = new CustomerPaymentApply();
paymentApply.setAmount(amount);
paymentApply.setApply(true);
paymentApply.setDoc(Long.valueOf(invoiceId));
```

Answer (score 0):

We were getting this error with the Chargebee-Netsuite integration. The solution was to open the corresponding Accounting Period in Netsuite and rerun the sync.

The first number `[123344,null]` is the Netsuite internal ID of the affected document. If you navigate to the document in Netsuite and it has a padlock this could be the reason:

[image: Locked document]

Open the Accounting Period for the affected document and rerun the sync. Setup/accounting/manage accounting periods:

[image: Manage accounting periods]